# Lambda 'special void-compatibility rule' - statement expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Im reading Java 8 in Action. In section 3.5.2 there is a paragraph about 'void-compatibility rule':

> If a lambda has a statement expression as its body, it’s compatible
>   with a function descriptor that returns void (provided the parameter
>   list is compatible too). For example, both of the following lines are
>   legal even though the method add of a List returns a boolean and not
>   void as expected in the Consumer context (T -> void):

```
// Predicate has a boolean return 
Predicate<String> p = s -> list.add(s); 
// Consumer has a void return 
Consumer<String> b = s -> list.add(s);
```

How would you describe 'statement expression' in general? I thought it was either statement or expression. Also this void-compatibility rule is not 100% clear to me, can you think of any other examples?

Comment: If it helps, an "expression statement" is a stand-alone statement followed by a semicolon and the returned value, if any, is ignored. Example `new Integer();` that is and stand-alone line of code. If expression statement is in a lambda expression body (not block body), and the function type of the target type returns void, then the returned value of the expression statement is ignored.Basically, the jsl says : a lambda of the form `() -> expr`, where `expr` is a statement expression, is interpreted as either `() -> { return expr; }` or `() -> { expr; }`, depending on the target type.

Answer (score 17):

The term “statement expression” or “expression statement” refers to expressions that are also allowed to be used as a statement. They are described in the Java Language Specification, [§14.8. Expression Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).

They include:

- Method Invocations
- Assignments
- Increment/Decrement expressions
- Class Instance Creation expressions

So other examples are:

```
Consumer<String> b = s -> counter++;
Function<String,Integer> f = s -> counter++;
```

or

```
Consumer<String> b = s -> new BigDecimal(s);
Function<String,BigDecimal> f = s -> new BigDecimal(s);
```

---

As a rule of thumb, a lambda expression of the form `x -> expression` is only legal for a `Consumer` (or `void` function type in general), if `x -> { expression; }` would be legal too.

Comment: can you elaborate it  more

Comment: @Deepak: which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

The common structure of lambda expression is that:

```
(parameter) -> {body};
```

**{body}** with a single line statement **return** statement is optional e.g.

```
Predicate<String> p = s -> list.add(s);
```

When braces are used **return** statement becomes mandatory e.g.

```
Predicate<String> p = s -> { return list.add(s);};
```

Now, consider a **Functional Interface** like **Consumer** with an abstract method which doesn't return any value. It can accept a statement which returns any value because compiler ignores **return** statement for such abstract methods.

And hence below statements holds true:

```
Consumer<String> b = s -> list.add(s);
```

Equivalent to:

```
Consumer<String> consumerExample = s -> {list.add(s);};
```

Below line is incorrect:

```
Consumer<String> consumerExample = s -> {return list.add(s);};
```

Therefore, if a lambda has statement expression as its body, its compatible with a function descriptor that returns void ***(provided that parameter list is compatible too)***.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the previous post clearly... I am trying in my way!!!

A function descriptor with explicit return value can be supplied for a lambda function descriptor which is do not return any value.

For Example, 
Predicate    T -> *vs* Consumer T -> void
lambda expression which takes an input and gives boolean as return, Predicate, can be supplied for Consumer.

In the following example, public boolean add(E e) {} returns boolean, but it can be used in the lambda for Consumer, which returns void.

```
    Predicate<String> p = s -> list.add(s);
    p.test("helloworld"); // this returns boolean 

    Consumer<String> consumerExample = s -> list.add(s);
    consumerExample.accept("Welcometokpm"); // this returns void
```