# Method Reference - passing Function to method with Consumer argument

Tags: java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I'm learning about Method References from Java 8 and I have difficulties understanding why does this work?

```
class Holder {
    private String holded;

    public Holder(String holded) {
        this.holded = holded;
    }

    public String getHolded() {
        return holded;
    }
}

private void run() {
    Function<Holder, String> getHolded = Holder::getHolded;

    consume(Holder::getHolded); //This is correct...
    consume(getHolded);         //...but this is not
}

private void consume(Consumer<Holder> consumer) {
    consumer.accept(null);
}
```

As you can see in `run` method - `Holder::getHolded` returns unbound method reference which you can invoke by passing object of type `Holder` as an argument. Like this: `getHolded.apply(holder)`

But why it casts this unbound method reference to `Consumer` when it is invoked directly as an method argument, and it does not doing it when I'm passing `Function` explicitly?

Comment: Note that you should also be able to `consumer(getHolded::apply)`.

Comment: By the way, “holded” should be “held”.

Comment: @Holger :) you are everywhere! I did not even notice, nice!

Comment: `consumer(getHolded::apply)` will fit right in on the same void compatibility rule as presented `consume(Holder::getHolded)` ;) the rule is mentioned by @Eugene below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things here, lambda expressions are poly expressions - they are *inferred* by the compiler using their context (like generics for example).

When you declare `consume(Holder::getHolded);`, compiler (under the so-called *special void compatibility rule*) will infer it to `Consumer<Holder>`.

And this might not look obvious, but think of a simplified example. It is generally more than ok do call a method and discard it's return type, right? For example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
```

Even if `list.add(1)` returns a boolean, we don't care about it.

Thus your example that works can be simplified to:

```
consume(x -> {
        x.getHolded(); // ignore the result here
        return;
});
```

So these are both possible and valid declarations:

```
Consumer<Holder> consumer = Holder::getHolded;
Function<Holder, String> function = Holder::getHolded;
```

But in this case we are *explicitly* telling what type is `Holder::getHolded`,, it's not the compiler inferring, thus `consume(getHolded);` fails, a `Consumer` != `Function` after all.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me understanding the whole wibbly wobbly stuff which is going on here. Especially the __special void compatibility rule__

Comment: @TomaszBielaszewski just notice that not everything fits into that rule, if I remember correctly there are only 4 types, method invocation, constructor invocation, increment/decrement and I forgot the last one :) search the JLS if you want...

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 introduced 4 important "function shapes" in the package `java.util.function`.

- **Consumer** -> accepts a method reference (or a lambda expression) that takes one argument but doesn't return anything
- **Supplier** -> accepts a method reference (or a lambda expression) that takes no argument and returns an object.
- **Function** -> accepts a method reference (or a lambda expression) that takes one argument and returns an object.
- **Predicate** -> accepts a method reference (or a lambda expression) that takes one argument and returns a boolean.

Read the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) for more detail.

To answer your question on why the first one works but the second one errors out, read following:

**The second statement**

`consume(getHolded);`

doesn't work because the type of the argument `getHolded` is `Function<Holder, String>` whereas the `consume` method expects an argument of type `Consumer<Holder>`. Since there is no parent-child relationship between `Function` and `Consumer`, it requires an explicit cast without which the compiler rightly errors out.

**The first statement**

`consume(Holder::getHolded);`

works because the method `getHolded` is declared as `public String getHolded()` meaning that it doesn't take any argument and returns a `String`. As per the new [void compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482574/lambda-special-void-compatibility-rule-statement-expression) rule, void types are inferred as the class containing the referenced method. Consider the following statement:

`Consumer<Holder> consumer = Holder::getHolded;`

This is a valid statement even though the method `getHolded` doesn't accept any arguments. This is allowed to facilitate inferring void types. Yet another example is the one you have mentioned yourself:

`Function<Holder, String> getHolded = Holder::getHolded;`

This is also a valid statement where you have said that the function object `getHolded` is a `Function` that returns `String` and accepts a type `Holder` even though the assigned method reference doesn't take any argument.

Comment: Really appreciated your breakdown of the 4 function shapes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing just a summary of the four types of Method References under the hood:

1. Reference to a static method:

   `Type::staticMethod ===>>> x -> Type.staticMethod(x)`
2. Reference to an instance method of a particular object:

   `instance::instanceMethod ===>>> x -> instance.instanceMethod(x)`
3. Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type:

   `Type::instanceMethod ===>>> x -> x.instanceMethod()   OR   (x, y) -> x.instanceMethod(y)`
4. Reference to a constructor:

   `Type::new ===> x -> new Type(x)`