# Compiler issue with IntConsumer returns Function.identity().apply()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

declaring an IntConsumer like this:

```
int z = 0;
IntConsumer iConsumer = (a) -> z;
```

gives a compilation error: "Void methods cannot return a value". **Ok**

But like this :

```
int z = 0;
IntConsumer iConsumer = (a) -> Function.identity().apply(z);
```

When `Function.identity().apply(z)` returns an `Object`, **no compilation error here.**

Shouldn't also give a compilation error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482574/lambda-special-void-compatibility-rule-statement-expression

Comment: This is a Function and not a "special" statement as described by that question you refer.

A Function, where: "R apply(T t)" method will always return R (which is not void), so the compiler knows at compile-time check that this method will never return void so why does it accept as valid and "forget" the value that is returned?

Comment: @fidudidu doesn't my post answer your question? `Function.identity().apply(z)` is an expression statement (specifically, a method invocation statement). From JLS: *"An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, the value is discarded."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z` is **always** an expression.

`Function.identity().apply(z)` is [**an expression statement**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8). It can be used as an expression since it returns a value. But it's interpreted as a statement as long as the value is being ignored.

> An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, **the value is discarded.**
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8</sup>

`IntConsumer#accept(int value)` expects `void` to be returned. In case of a single-line lambda body, it must be a statement.

Compare

```
// not allowed - expressions
IntConsumer a = (i) -> 2 + 2;
IntConsumer b = (i) -> true ? 1 : 0;
IntConsumer c = (i) -> (Function.identity().apply(i));
IntConsumer d = (i) -> (System.out.println(i));
IntConsumer e = (i) -> (new Object());

// allowed - expression statements
IntConsumer f = (i) -> Function.identity().apply(i);
IntConsumer g = (i) -> System.out.println(i);
IntConsumer h = (i) -> new Object();
```